# SED command to delete a forward slash "/" between 2 tags

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

I am using Linux, and I want to use `sed` to delete a forward slash (`/`) between 2 tags. From this:

```
<file>/text</file>
<file>/text2</file
<file>/text</file>..
```

to this

```
<file>text</file>
<file>text2</file
<file>text</file>..
```

Test a lot of code without success
exemple:

```
sed s'/<file>/s|^\.{1,2}/||' fileout
```

can you help?

Comment: If you really want to use `sed`: `sed '/<file>/s|<file>/|<file>|'`

Comment: `sed 's|>/|>|'` would do it. You may want to more clearly specify under what condition a `/` should be removed.

Comment: Thank a lot this work fine,

Answer (score 3):

Given a well-formed XML file, such as

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <file>/text</file>
  <file>/text2</file>
  <file>/text</file>
  <file>other text</file>
</root>
```

... you may use XMLStarlet to remove the first character of each `file` node's value if the value starts with a `/`:

```bash
xmlstarlet edit \
    --update '//file[starts-with(text(), "/")]' \
    --expr 'substring(text(), 2)' \
    myfile.xml
```

Or, using shorter syntax,

```bash
xmlstarlet ed \
    -u '//file[starts-with(text(), "/")]' \
    -x 'substring(text(), 2)' \
    myfile.xml
```

This finds each `file` node in the whole input document whose value starts with `/`, and then removes that first character by using `substring()`.

The result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <file>text</file>
  <file>text2</file>
  <file>text</file>
  <file>other text</file>
</root>
```

This (and the below) would deal with nodes whose values contain embedded newlines.

---

Would you want to detect the `/` anywhere in the value, not just at the start, and if you want to remove them all, you may do so using `contains()` and `translate()` instead:

```bash
xmlstarlet edit \
    --update '//file[contains(text(), "/")]' \
    --expr 'translate(text(), "/", "")' \
    myfile.xml
```

Or just (because the `translate()` call would leave values unchanged if there were no `/` in them),

```bash
xmlstarlet edit \
    --update '//file' \
    --expr 'translate(text(), "/", "")' \
    myfile.xml
```

Given this input file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <file>text/</file>
  <file>/text/2</file>
  <file>te/x/t/</file>
  <file>other text</file>
</root>
```

... the above command would produce the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <file>text</file>
  <file>text2</file>
  <file>text</file>
  <file>other text</file>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Input (fixed syntax) `XML` file (missed closing `>` on second `file` node):

```
<r>
<file>/text</file>
<file>/text2</file>
<file>/text</file>
</r>
```

With modern syntax and the proper `XPath`'s function [`fn:replace()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-translate) (kind of `sed` for `XPath`, allowing the use of regexes and *capture group* with `XPath` version >= 2), using `XQuery`, you can do:

```
xidel --xquery '
    <r>{
        for $x in //file
        return <file>{replace($x, "^/(.*)", "$1")}</file> 
    }</r>
' --output-format=xml file.xml
```

That yields:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r>
<file>text</file>
<file>text2</file>
<file>text</file>
</r>
```

---

If you need to edit the file on the fly, use `sponge`, a tool from `GNU` `more-utils`:

```
xidel ... file.xml | sponge file.xml
```

---

- overview of regexes in `XPath/XQuery` https://www.regular-expressions.info/xpath.html
- `XPath` is a subset of `XQuery`. Check [difference-between-xpath-xquery-and-xpointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924551/difference-between-xpath-xquery-and-xpointer#924594)
- [`xidel`](https://github.com/benibela/xidel) is the Swiss army knife for manipulating HTML/XML.
- you can also use the `XQuery` processor (Open source) [`BaseX`](https://basex.org/) to execute `XQuery` expressions

Comment: Using now regex to match `^/`

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two forward slashes on each line of the input you can try this awk command:

```
$ awk  'BEGIN{OFS=FS="/"}{printf "%s", $1;print$2,$3}' input_file
<file>text</file>
<file>text2</file
<file>text</file>
```

You would need to re-position printf and print depending on which forward slash you want removed.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*...with Raku's (community-supported) `XML` module:*

```
~$ raku -MXML -e 'my  $xml = open-xml( $*ARGFILES.Str );
                  for $xml.elements( :RECURSE(0), :TAG{"file"} ) -> $E {
                      my $old = $E.contents[0];
                      my $new = XML::Text.new( text => $old.text.subst(/^ "/" /) );
                      $E.replace( $old, $new );
                  };  .say for $xml;'   file.xml
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family that features high-level [Grammars](https://dev.to/jj/introduction-to-grammars-with-perl6-75e) for parsing text. Above using its native [XML-Grammar](https://github.com/raku-community-modules/XML/blob/main/lib/XML/Grammar.rakumod) engine, Raku's object-oriented `XML` module parses the input `XML` file. XML-Elements are thus identified and can be iterated through.

A problem with Regex-only (e.g. `sed`) solutions for `XML` is substitutions tend to be promiscuous: you often have difficulty restricting substutions only to certain depths/TAGs. In Raku with the `XML`-module, you can (for example) limit replacements to 1). the top-level and 2). within only the `<file>` TAG. This is done by setting the code to iterate through `elements` with the limitations `:RECURSE(0), :TAG{"file"}`. Here, `:NEST` can be added as well to only iterate through `EVEN` nodes.

*[ Not to worry if you want to iterate through all `TAG`s at all depths: simply set `:RECURSE(Inf)` and remove the `:TAG` named-argument, which sets the `:TAG` restriction to False ].*

Thus identified, each element's internal (i.e. non-TAG) `contents[0]` are assigned to the variable `$old`, which is actually an `XML::Text` object. The `$old` object is `.text` extracted into a string, and `subst`ituted with nothing to remove the offending `"/"` forward-slash. A new (`XML::Text.new`) object is created (`$new`) with the now-corrected `text => 'value'` key/value pair. From here the `XML`-module's `replace` routine completes the job: `replace( $old, $new )`.

Sample Input (thanks to @Kusalananda!):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <file>/text</file>
  <file>/text2</file>
  <file>/text</file>
  <file>other text</file>
</root>
```

Sample Output (leading-`/` is removed from <file> tags):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?><root>
  <file>text</file>
  <file>text2</file>
  <file>text</file>
  <file>other text</file>
</root>
```

https://github.com/raku-community-modules/XML
https://raku.land/?q=XML
https://rakudo.org/
https://raku.org